# I want to add a comment mark to the end of every if statement in python code, how can I do it?

Tags: python, regex

Here's a piece of code that doesn't make sense:

```
if aaa=1:
# dfdf fdf
  xxx
  if cc = 4:
    rrr
  else:
    ww
    if aaaaa:
      # dssfdsf
      ttt
    # endif
  # endif
elif bb=2:

  if ll is True:
    return
  # endif
  yyy
else:
  zzz
# endif
dfsdfsaa
```

The **#endif** is the *comment mark* I want to add, I tried to do it with regular expressions ( [regex101Example](https://regex101.com/r/qY6dS0/6)), but it didn't work, who has a better idea?

Comment: It seems that the comment after the if are not well indented : these should be at same level as if contents not if line.

Comment: @PtitXav well...is there any solution?

Comment: I think it will be very difficult with regex. The way to determine the end of id is to find the next code line with less or equal indentation as the if or the else. This can only be done by parsing the file and memorising the current indent level (including also the while, def, class, … (xxx:)  that generates indentation.

Comment: @PtitXav Can you provide an idea? How to parse the file and determine the indentation level?

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to be a solution:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re
test_str = ("if aaa=1:\n"
    "# dfdf fdf\n"
    "  xxx\n"
    "  if cc = 4:\n"
    "    rrr\n"
    "  else:\n"
    "    ww\n"
    "    if aaaaa:\n"
    "      # dssfdsf\n"
    "      ttt\n"
    "elif bb=2:\n\n"
    "  if ll is True:\n"
    "    return\n"
    "  yyy\n"
    "else:\n"
    "  zzz\n"
    "dfsdfsaa")
regex = r"^( *)(if(.|\n)+?^(?!\1  |#|\1el|\n))"
subst = "\\1#\\2\\1# endif\\n"
matches = re.match(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
# Assuming a maximum nesting of 6 levels
for i in range(6):
  if matches:
    test_str = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
result = re.sub(r"#if ", "if ",test_str, )
print(result)
```

Modified according to [Code Generator](https://regex101.com/r/qY6dS0/6/codegen?language=python) by [regex101Example](https://regex101.com/r/qY6dS0/6). I have been trying to implement directly through regex's recursion and other methods, but no success...

Output:

```
if aaa=1:
# dfdf fdf
  xxx
  if cc = 4:
    rrr
  else:
    ww
    if aaaaa:
      # dssfdsf
      ttt
    # endif
  # endif
elif bb=2:

  if ll is True:
    return
  # endif
  yyy
else:
  zzz
# endif
dfsdfsaa
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).